# Block the [meta-tag:block]s?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

[blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked)<sub>× 26</sub> and [block](/questions/tagged/block)<sub>gone!</sub> appear to be Kinda Ambiguous Meta-Meta-Tags™. Blocked content, possibly-blocked JS, auto-blocking on failed SSL ads, downvoted ads not getting blocked, being blocked from asking questions (lots), WebSense blocking things, discussion about being blocked from asking questions, discussion about blocking Tor, blocking of rep gains from old posts, problems with code blocks, being blocked from chat, blocking of whatever the heck YQL is, blocking of Opera Mini, blocking of crawlers, blocked (a.k.a. ignored) tags...

[image: Can we get rid of them? Please?]

Comment: [meta-tag:block] is gone now.